# UITableView doesn't respond to scroll when parent frame is repositioned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm building something similar to the Twitter composition panel in their mobile app.  The top half of the view has a text area while the bottom half is a table view of images.  You can scroll the table view up and it'll push the top view offscreen and only then you can scroll up and down the table view.  What I have done is place my table view in a wrapper view and I change the frame of this to move both the tableview and the top view up and down (using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`).  The problem I have is once the wrapper view has moved up from its original position, only the section of the tableview which was originally visible can be scrolled.  The previously offscreen part cannot scroll.  Events are still bubbling up a couple view above.

Code below:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.superview.frame.size.height;
    [self.tableView setFrame:frame];

    self.tableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.tableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.tableView.index = index;

    self.panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    self.panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1.0;
    self.panGesture.delegate = self;

    self.panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    self.panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan =YES;
    self.panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;


    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:self.panGesture];
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` action ?

Comment: The fact that you've done it without any code is amazing, however it makes the question much more difficult to answer.

Comment: The usual geek sarcasm doesn't help things either.

Comment: Can you show the code of your handlePanGesture ?

Comment: It doesn't even hit this code for the section of the table view which was previously offscreen.  It's as-if the touch events have only been applied to the original frame size.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that handlePanGesture is not reached? Is it the scroll or the pan which is not working ?

Comment: No, the UITableView doesn't scroll.  I have it responding to both a pan gesture and the default list scrolling at the same time.  Both work together fine, apart from the lower section where is doesn't respond to any touch events.  One thing I failed to mention is that this is wrapped within a UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

It was a sizing issue for the table view.  Although it appeared to be sized correctly, it was not which meant the content size was incorrect and therefore why the scroll didn't function as expected.